# GetOrgChart - InsertNode without expanding it directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, lazy-evaluation, getorgchart

is it somehow possible to insert a Node with getorgchart.js without expanding the node directly? 
I want to dynamically insert a node (with the insertNode method).
But the node should be collapsed.

Is it maybe somehow possible in the renderEvent or updatedEvent methods?
I'm trying to implement a kind of lazy loading feature where the nodes are dynamically loaded + inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to insert the node without expanding the node directly.
I set the `args.node.collapsed` attribute to 1 when the node is rendered. So the node is collapsed after rendering.

```
function renderNodeEvent(sender, args) {
    args.node.collapsed = 1;
}

orgChart.insertNode(ID);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use "expandOrCollapse" method provided by the api which takes node id as parameter and expand or collapse the specific node based on its state.
e.g. expandOrCollapse(id).
Where 'id' is node id which is just created.
So after creating the node just call above line of code.
For more details you can refer to below link:
http://www.getorgchart.com/QuickStart/Methods/expandOrCollapse.html

Comment: The problem is that when I insert the node and afterwards I use the "expandOrCollapse" method then the inserted node can be seen by the user before it will be collapsed. I don't want that. But I was able to get it working. See my answer below.